# AWS APIGateway Lambda proxy integration- Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I am relatively new to AWS and the beast. After working on API Gateway to Lambda proxy integration I am getting `Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function`

I followed below setup referred from really well documented `terraform documentation` and does exactly what was needed for me. But while testing on API Gateway console giving the above error.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
    statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.resource_name.arn}"
    principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

    # The /*/* portion grants access from any method on any resource
    # within the API Gateway "REST API".
    source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.resource_name_of_deployment.execution_arn}/*/*"
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Few learnings from API Gateway Lambda proxy integration

- API Gateway is deployed in different stages and ARN for API gateway in stage vs on test console is somewhat different. (atleast thats what I got on terraform output)

As many documentations and fixes for the problem suggests to explicitly configure detailed path as `"arn:aws:execute-api:region_name:account_id:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_resource.id}/*/*"` 
The configured source with granted access permission

```
 arn:aws:execute-api:region:accountid:fu349z93pa/*/*
```

From terraform documentation
  For `"${aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment_rsc_name.execution_arn}"`

The configured source with granted access permission is

```
arn:aws:execute-api:region:accountid:fu349z93pa/stage/*/*
```

If you test from API Gateway console you would end up with same error and have to manually add permission to lambda or reselect lambda function name on method integration console (which does the same thing). That configures 2 API gateways to access Lambda. (one with `/stage` deployed ARN and other `/*/METHOD/*` - `used for test console`) 
[image: Lambda console]

But if you test API gateway from ARN of stage environment on postman it works just as fine without any manual updates to infrastructure built with terraform. And in most cases that is the one that would matter.

- Even after fixing first error manually / not second challenge is `Malformed response from lambda`

This one is fairly easy and well documented. [AWS Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)

All we have to do is update lambda to respond with a specified format.

for. e.g. add below

```
callback(null, { "statusCode": 200, "body" : JSON.stringify(sampleResponseJSON) }); on lambda `js`
```

Once it is working end to end we could always add error handling scenarios.

Hopefully, this should save some time for beginners like me.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response here. Simply changing the `source_arn` on the "aws_lambda_permission" as you suggest works.

Answer (score 5):

So instead of using:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
    ... ...
    source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.resource_name_of_deployment.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

I use the `replace` method to remove the `stage_name` from the `execution_arn`:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
    ... ...
    source_arn = "${replace(aws_api_gateway_deployment.resource_name_of_deployment.execution_arn, var.stage_name, "")}*/*"
}
```

And now everything works for me